# Crontab inactive?

Tags: cron, cron-task

This is my first project with crontab so I am unsure what I am doing wrong

I was under the assumption you wrote something like

```
0 * * * *  /home/pi/dir/file
```

But my code is

```
0,30 * * * * /home/pi/ES/logTemp.py
```

but nothing appears to be working. I checked

```
service cond status
```

and got

```
cond.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: no such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

I double checked and I wrote the directory (I think) correctly and that is the name of my file I want to run.

Any tips for a newbie?

Comment: `service` (or `systemctl status`) and `cron` have nothing to do with one another. Are you trying to run a service or run a specific task on a schedule?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to run a task every 30 minutes

Comment: Then `service` is entirely unrelated. `systemd` does support timer units that can be used like cronjobs but that's different from a normal service and not what you are doing if you are writing a line like that as a traditional cronjob. cron jobs don't have a "status". They run when they are configured to and the rest of the time they aren't active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using correct code to schedule the crontab, just restart the cron and it would work.

but the command you are executing to check the status is incorrect. i.e. you are using **cond** instead of **c*r*ond**(service cond status).

1.
You can try the below code.(its same of your code)

> */30 * * * * /home/pi/ES/logTemp.py

2. 

**To restart the cron, *Run***

> service crond restart

3. 

**And to check status of cron, *Run***

> service crond status

Use **sudo** if logged in using other username than **root**

Comment: I just realized I needed to put sudo in front of these commands.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this did it.